# Configure CentOS run command prompt

Tags: centos

How do I configure the run command prompt (the one shown with `Alt+F2`) in CentOS 7?  It doesn't appear to be seeing my PATH or aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Set a file with aliases,variables,PS1,etc and then source it
for example

```
edit .bash_profile
source .bash_profile
```